# Esp8266 unlinking very fast

Tags: esp8266

Pls how do I get the length of the following GET request

GET /data/2.5/weather?q=San%20Francisco,us HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: api.openweathermap.org\r\n\r\n\r\n

GET /api/weather/insert.php?temp=74.6&him=40.0 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: symbiotictech.000webhostapp\r\n\r\n\r\n

Again my esp8266 unlink very quickly when Linking to my server (am using 000webhost...N/b: *Free*) but when I connect/link to other websites e.g *openweather.org* it stays longer and return response before unlinking, what should I do.

Comment: What do you "unlink very quickly"? You mean it disconnects before you get an answer? You have an extra `\r\n` which is not needed but I doubt that is the reason. Is your host correct? Are you connecting on the right port? Is there maybe a mixup between TLS and no TLS? Is the webservice correctly answering when using e.g. `curl`? Also if you webservice actually **inserts** data, it must not be a `GET`. It must be a `POST` or possibly a `PUT`.

Comment: Ok. I will try POST, but I have  actually used GET for other websites without issues, and I think the host, port and everything is correct, I also used POSTMAN and it worked....

Comment: I thought you had changed the Host in your second request, but you really just missed the `.com` at the end, didn't you?